# typescript / jscript side-by-side in Visual Studio 2013 update 3

Tags: typescript

Since installing VS 2013 update 3, I haven't seen the option to display the JScript output side-by-side with the Typescript source as I seem to remember using earlier Web Essentials support.  Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: Install Web Essentials again? Or re-enable the option that may have been disabled? Or upgrade it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to enable it in the Web Essentials options.
Tools --> Options and choose Web Essentials and TypeScript on the left side

Screenshot:
[image: Imgur]